# How can I order a list of dictionaries based on another list which has the key?

Tags: python, sorting

I have some ids as follows:

```
req_ids=['964','123','534','645','876','222']
```

and I get a response from another server like this not in any particular order:

```
res_result = [{'id':'123', 'name':'Sachin'},
              {'id':'534', 'name':'Vipin'},
              {'id':'222', 'name':'Ram'},
              {'id':'645', 'name':'Anoop'},
              {'id':'964', 'name':'Sani'},
              {'id':'876', 'name':'John'}]
```

I need to get `res_result` in the same request order as req_ids,

```
    [{'id':'964', 'name':'Sani'},
     {'id':'123', 'name':'Sachin'},
     {'id':'534', 'name':'Vipin'},
     {'id':'645', 'name':'Anoop'},
     {'id':'876', 'name':'John'},
     {'id':'222', 'name':'Ram'}]
```

How do I do this if possible using an inbuilt python function instead writing our own loop to do this logic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you *must* sort, map the keys to integers, then use that map to sort:

```
id_to_pos = {key: i for i, key in enumerate(req_ids)}
sorted(res_result, key=lambda d: id_to_pos[d['id']])
```

Demo:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> req_ids = ['964', '123', '534', '645', '876', '222']
>>> res_result = [{'id':'123', 'name':'Sachin'},
...               {'id':'534', 'name':'Vipin'},
...               {'id':'222', 'name':'Ram'},
...               {'id':'645', 'name':'Anoop'},
...               {'id':'964', 'name':'Sani'},
...               {'id':'876', 'name':'John'}]
>>> id_to_pos = {key: i for i, key in enumerate(req_ids)}
>>> sorted(res_result, key=lambda d: id_to_pos[d['id']])
[{'id': '964', 'name': 'Sani'}, {'id': '123', 'name': 'Sachin'}, {'id': '534', 'name': 'Vipin'}, {'id': '645', 'name': 'Anoop'}, {'id': '876', 'name': 'John'}, {'id': '222', 'name': 'Ram'}]
>>> pprint(_)
[{'id': '964', 'name': 'Sani'},
 {'id': '123', 'name': 'Sachin'},
 {'id': '534', 'name': 'Vipin'},
 {'id': '645', 'name': 'Anoop'},
 {'id': '876', 'name': 'John'},
 {'id': '222', 'name': 'Ram'}]
```

However, you can avoid sorting altogether, you *already* have the right order, you only need to map from `id` keys to dictionaries (O(N)), then pull out the dictionaries in the right order (still O(N)):

```
id_to_dict = {d['id']: d for d in res_result}
[id_to_dict[id] for id in req_ids]
```

Demo:

```
>>> id_to_dict = {d['id']: d for d in res_result}
>>> [id_to_dict[id] for id in req_ids]
[{'id': '964', 'name': 'Sani'}, {'id': '123', 'name': 'Sachin'}, {'id': '534', 'name': 'Vipin'}, {'id': '645', 'name': 'Anoop'}, {'id': '876', 'name': 'John'}, {'id': '222', 'name': 'Ram'}]
>>> pprint(_)
[{'id': '964', 'name': 'Sani'},
 {'id': '123', 'name': 'Sachin'},
 {'id': '534', 'name': 'Vipin'},
 {'id': '645', 'name': 'Anoop'},
 {'id': '876', 'name': 'John'},
 {'id': '222', 'name': 'Ram'}]
```

Comment: It the complexity O(n^2)?

Comment: @FazalSap: no, O(NlogN), simply straight-up sort; the `id_to_pos` map makes looking up the sort key a O(1) operation, per sorted item. The map is created in O(N) time, *before* the sort. So the overall algorithm is still dominated by the O(NlogN) sorting time.

Comment: @FazalSap: but now that you made me think properly, I added a O(N) solution instead. No need to sort when you already have a fixed order, all you need is to produce a map from id to dictionary.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - dict lookup `id_to_dict[id]` can be O(n) if there is a collision right? So the worst case is O(n^2) no? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Nishant: chances of a collision are *way too small* to matter here. Yes, in theory you can [craft all-colliding keys](http://www.ocert.org/advisories/ocert-2011-003.html), but with [hash randomisation](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHASHSEED) the chances of running into *N* hash collisions is virtually zero.

Comment: Ok @MartijnPieters thanks for all practical purposes I am sure it will work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> map({d['id']: d for d in res_result}.__getitem__, req_ids)
[{'id': '964', 'name': 'Sani'}, {'id': '123', 'name': 'Sachin'}, {'id': '534', 'name': 'Vipin'}, {'id': '645', 'name': 'Anoop'}, {'id': '876', 'name': 'John'}, {'id': '222', 'name': 'Ram'}]
```